# react-loadable import dynamicaly object with components as properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic-import, react-loadable

I have an index file where I export all of my SVG components:

```
import Twitter from './Twitter';
import Upload from './Upload';
import Cloud from './Cloud';
import Share from './Share';
import Eye from './Eye';
import Trash from './Trash';
import Search from './Search';

export {
  Facebook,
  Twitter,
  Upload,
  Cloud,
  Share,
  Eye,
  Trash,
  Search,
};
```

Then later in the app, I use them like:

```
import * as Icons from './index.js';

<Icons.Twitter />
...
<Icons.Search />
```

because I have a lot of these icons I would like to load them asynchronously with `react-lodable`.

I tried:

```
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import PulsingCircleLoader from '../PulsingCircleLoader';

const Icons = Loadable({
  loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "icons" */ './index'),
  loading: () => <PulsingCircleLoader isLoading />,
});

export default Icons;
```

But this gives me an error:

> warning.js?6327:33 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid --
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
>   up default and named imports

that's probably because `Icons.Twitter` is at some point an `PulsingCircleLoader` with no static `Twitter` property.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are importing your icons with `export { ... }` statement. But when you are using call like this `import(/* webpackChunkName: "icons" */ './index'),` the `./index` file must have `export default` statement

Comment: I don't think that's the case because before `Icons` are dynamically loaded, react-loadable will return `PulsingCircleLoader` which has no static properties. If I'm wrong please prepare some example on code sandbox.